Jetpack Compose strange transition using AnimatedContent between Text & Box Layout
I explore about Jetpack Compose, and create a simple PIN Indicator composable view. I add AnimatedContent to switch between two composable: Text & Box Layout.
However, i found strange transition from Box to Text like image below (there is n char when I delete value):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-fYcsiLsody5LBjTOFy6lHdkCQItl-G/view?usp=sharing
My composable snippet is like below:
@Composable
fun AppPin(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    maxLength: Int = 4,
    values: List<Int> = listOf(),
    onInputPin: (Int) -> Unit,
    onRemovePin: () -> Unit
) {
    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    var lastInputPin by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier.height(40.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(40.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            for (i in 0..<maxLength) {
                AppPinIndicator(values.getOrNull(i))
            }
        }
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = lastInputPin,
            onValueChange = {
                lastInputPin = it
                if (it.length < values.size) {
                    onRemovePin()
                } else {
                    onInputPin(it.lastOrNull()?.toString()?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0)
                }
            },
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Color.Transparent
            ),
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(Color.Transparent),
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal
            )
        )
    }
}

@Composable
    fun AppPinIndicator(value: Int? = null) {
        AnimatedContent(targetState = value, label = "") {
            if (it == null) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)
                        .background(
                            color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) InputDarkColor else NeutralColor,
                            shape = CircleShape
                        )
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(24.dp),
                    text = value.toString(),
                    style = ChateoTheme.typography.headlineLarge
                )
            }
        }
}

How to fix that? Thank you

That n is initial letter of "null" String and it happens because an item is removed from Composition when transition is over. If you add a check on text of String or display it when state is not null such as
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.width(24.dp),
    text = it.toString(),
)

To observe change during animation state change you can see by adding a log such as
@Composable
fun AppPinIndicator(
    index: Int,
    value: Int? = null
) {
    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = value,
        label = ""
    ) {

        println("index: $index, State: $it, value: $value")

        if (it == null) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(24.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = Color.Gray,
                        shape = CircleShape
                    )
            )
        } else {
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.width(24.dp),
    text = it.toString(),
)
        }
    }
}

For instance, if the last item is 9 and you remove last item it will log
 I  index: 3, State: 9, value: null
 I  index: 3, State: null, value: null
 I  index: 3, State: null, value: null
 I  index: 3, State: null, value: null
 I  index: 3, State: null, value: null

As you can see value is null but state turns to null later

Thank you for the insight! I solve it by checking the value paramater is null or not.
